# 100vw Navbar overlapping scrollbar when overflow-y is applied

Tags: html, css, reactjs

I'm having a little trouble with styling a 100vw navbar with page sections that have 100vh. I also included a 'snap' effect to the pages which snaps to the page when the user scrolls. The main issue is that the navbar is overlapping with the scrollbar and I'm unsure how to fix it. I want the navbar to start at the top of the page and not below the nav either. It looks like if I remove the overflow-y: scroll in the app.css content the scroll bar appears normally but I lose the scrolling effect. Can anyone give me insight on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks

App js

```
import './App.css';
import { Navbar } from './components/Navbar';
import { Body } from './components/Body'

function App() {
  return (
    <>
      <div className="header">
          <Navbar></Navbar>
      </div>
      <div className="content">
          <Body></Body>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}

export default App;
```

App CSS

```
*{
  font-family: 'Nunito Sans', sans-serif;
}
div{
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.header{
  display: block;
}
.content{
  scroll-snap-type: y mandatory;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

Navbar

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/Navbar.css'
export const Navbar = () => {

    return (
        <>
            <div className = "navbar"></div>
        </>
    )
}
```

Navbar CSS

```
*{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.navbar{
    background-color: #343434;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center;
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    min-height: 8vh;
}
```

Body

```
import React from 'react'
import '../styles/Body.css'

export const Body = () => {
    return (
    <>
        <section className = "one">
            <h1>stuff</h1>
        </section>
        <section className = "two">
            <h1>stuff</h1>
        </section>
        <section className = "three">
             <h1>stuff</h1>
        </section>
        <section className = "four">
             <h1>stuff</h1>
        </section>
        <section className = "five">
            <h1>stuff</h1>
        </section>
    </>
    )

}
```

body CSS

```
*{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

section {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    scroll-snap-align: start;
    color: white;
    padding-top: 8vh;
    height: 100vh;
}
.one{
    background-color: rgb(36,164,138);
}
.two{
    background-color: rgb(211,79,79);
}
.three{
    background-color: rgb(67,91,175);
}
.four{
    background-color: lightsalmon;
}
.five{
    background-color: lightskyblue;
}
```

Comment: Are you using bootstrap?

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention I'm using React

Comment: That didn't answer the question. Bootstrap is often used _with_ React. 100vw does just what it says, without regard for scrollbars. You probably want 100% (or nothing, as divs are full width by default).